# How to keep a simple input string text in the local memory of Windows Phone to use in future?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, serialization

I try to get the email address of the user at the start up and use it for the later cases. I followed the instructions of http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners?page=3 but it needs to define an object and serialize, deserialize it. Is there any simpler way for a simple string variable?

Comment: Assuming you want to keep it in memory for the lifetime of your process, and not after the processes lifetime,  you can create a class level variable?

Comment: it should be called for any run not for life time

Comment: `Is there any simpler way for a simple string variable?` Sorry but this sounds like *"I am too lazy too tead documenations and to learn a new thing. I am looking for someone to write it for me"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remember the email address so the user won't need to enter it again you could use `IsolatedStorageSettings`.It is basically a dictionary that writes to isolated storage. Storing a username is almost as simple as:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("emailaddress", emailaddress);
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

And then to retrieve it:

```
var emailadress = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["emailaddress"];
```